# Cross UserControl property setting and persisting values

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, user-controls

I'm using a set of UserControls on a ASP.NET application which I'm maintaining.

I have a page which renders a set of custom UserControls. On one of these controls, lets say `ucA`, I may have a little Javascript Popup which render another UserControl and let's call this one `ucB`.
On `ucA` I've defined a public property which sets or gets values from a hiddenField defined in `ucA`:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidWorkDirName" runat="server" />
```

and the property definition:

```
public string _hidWorkDirName
{
    get { return hidWorkDirName.Value; }
    set { hidWorkDirName.Value = value; }
}
```

My `ucB` only shows a Textbox which, upon submit, should set the value of the `hidWorkDirName`:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ucA parent = (ucA)this.Parent; //this, being ucB
    parent._hidWorkDirName = txtName.Text; //the TextBox value being set on ucA
}
```

While debugging I can see that the value is set correctly.

Now, `ucA` also has a Submit button (both submits are for different things) on which I want to read the value of the `hidWorkDirName`. But no matter what I try the value I get is always an empty string as if nothing had been set.

I've tried reading the value directly from the hiddenField and from the property itself (`_hidWorkDirName`) but I never get the value I've set previsouly.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `Hiddenfield` `hidWorkDirName` could get reset during the `Page_Load`. Try a different approach using `ViewState`.

Here's your property with `ViewState`

```
public string _hidWorkDirName
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["WorkDirName"] != null)
        {
            return (string)ViewState["WorkDirName"];
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["WorkDirName"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That really was the answer. Thank you! Remind me to buy youa beer on of these days.. ;)

Comment: Had forgot that, sorry ;)